# How to copy a list from one class to another class in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want to copy a list from one class to another blank list in other class , also the problem is that there are two screens in my app which can be accessed by the bottom navigation bar and both the classes are in different screens .

Basically there is a button in the first screen that adds user input into a list in the same class of the first page , but now i want to use the same list in the second screen , so either i can copy the list from first page's class to second page's class or i can add the user input to both the page's list initially while the input is received , but i don't know how to do both of methods... if anyone could help me by giving an example then it would help a lot

i tried surfing the web on how to send data from one class to other class but they tell me about the MaterialPageRoute method which sends me to other page on pressing a button which is not what i want , instead i just want to send data to other page's class without actually shifting to the page on pressing a button

Comment: Are you talking about reusing the same widget or about data transferring?

Comment: data transferring

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in one of the classes

```dart
class A {
 A(this.a);
 final int a;
 
 B toB() {
    return B(
    b: a,
  }
}  

class B {
 B(this.b);
 final int b;
}
```

To be used like `final bInstance = aInstance.toB();` meaning you declared somewhere `aInstance = A(1);`

Comment: @Udbhav This solution should be sufficient for your requirement.